# Laravel app wildcard Digitalocean nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4, digital-ocean

I have set up a Laravel app at Digitalocean (nginx).

It works fine when I go to site.com but when I go to www.site.com it won't load.

My question is how should I set up the DNS record at Digitalocean and how should i set the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

1. www.site.com/path should redirect to site.com/path.
2. all the subdomain should refer to the main app site.
3. media.site.com should refer to other directory.

Thank you!

This is the file now:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/hzofe/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name media.site.com;
    ....
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name *.site.com;
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it fails, 'duplicate listen options for [::]:80'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tries adding a cname record for DNS redirect?

Also, if you are using https you can make one cert for the alias domain and your regular with lets-encrypt.

This is a nodejs tutorial but it may help...

https://code.lengstorf.com/deploy-nodejs-ssl-digitalocean/#install-nginx